# Why pdf annotation Y position starts from the bottom of the page in ios, pdfkit, swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdf-annotations

I tried to add an annotation to the page in pdf. it works. but not in the desired position. here is the way I added annotation.

```
let annotaionpos = CGRect(origin: points, size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 30))
let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: annotaionpos, forType: .text, withProperties: nil)
annotation.backgroundColor = .purple
pdfView.currentPage?.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

in above code, the `x position` is correct and the `y position` seems like opposite value. `ex: if x = 100 and y = 10` then it added to the correct **x position** and **y position stars from the bottom of the page**. why is this. hope your help with this.

Comment: Hello Marlon, can you please share the screenshot of expected result and what you are getting?

Comment: Because PDF coordinates are defined that way. "The origin, or 0,0 point is located in the bottom left hand corner of the page. Horizontal, or X, coordinates increase to the rights and vertical, or Y, coordinates increase towards the top" https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/PDF-Page-Coordinates.cfm

Answer (score 0):

The Apple develop document should be helped.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Conc/PDFKit_Prog_Conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH201-CHDIGGFD

[Figure: View space versus page space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3WAn.png)

Comment: While providing a documentation link is a good practice, you could at least try to extract parts of it which you believe would help with the original question.